# How to embed animated svg file on WordPress website

Tags: php, html, wordpress, svg, svg-animate

So I have this SVG file that has animation that I'm trying to use on a WordPress Website.
I've tried a lot of ways and none seems to be workings so far.

1st try

```
<img class="icon" src="url of the image uploaded on worpress media" alt="icon">
```

---

2nd try

```
<object class="icon" type="image/svg+xml" data="url of the image uploaded on worpress media"></object>
```

---

3rd try

```
<object class="icon" type="image/svg+xml" data="url of the image uploaded on worpress media">
    <img class="icon" src="url of the image uploaded on worpress media" alt="icon">
</object>
```

---

4th try

```
<img class="icon" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/icon.svg" alt="icon">
```

---

5th try

```
Inline code of <svg></svg>. Then I moved the script part of the svg at the bottom of the file
```

---

6th try

```
Even tried to use <amination> tags and separate all data from the svg file..which was Painfull.
```

PS: I read somewhere that Uploading a moving SVG wont work, especially on media uploaders like WordPress's media upload plugin even if rendered inline. So I search for a site that uploading a moving SVG "will make it work"...well..it didn't.

PS2: Yes, I also have the plugin SVG Support

Comment: Do you have any caching plugin installed or any plugin which compress the image on frontend ?

Comment: Its sure not cache issue. About the compress plug in, i only have the SVG Support plugin

Comment: What happens when you type in the URL for the SVG in your browser? Does it show up in the browser as expected?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was in the SVG file.
The way it was exported, it had a script in it, which wasnt running.
I exported it with CSS properties and that make the file from 300lines, to 20 lines. Then i added the animation that was in the SVG at my CSS file and its all perfect.
(Used SVG tags)